# How to improve performance of meteor web application

Tags: javascript, performance, docker, meteor, mup

My Meteor application is deployed on aws EC2 large instance with 8gb ram and 50 gb storage using Mup, My application have more than 30 clients, It slows down at any time in a day i.e. pages keeps on loading.

please suggest load balancing techniques for meteor.

It works fine and smooth on local environment, but slows down in production.
I have minimised subscriptions and loaded minimum amount of data in all pages.
Application works fine for sometime when instance is restarted.

Comment: 30 users should not kill your system performance, you should probably look at how the code performs and optimise that before you go to load balancing. You could start by using Kadira to identify the bottlenecks

Comment: Hi Mikkel, please provide link for kadira, I am not able to install from atmospherJS

Answer (score 0):

Following up on your request for Kadira - it is a meteor package itself, there is an announcement of it becoming open source in 2017 here: https://blog.meteor.com/kadira-apm-is-now-open-source-490469ffc85f

The github repo is here: https://github.com/kadira-open/kadira-server

This hasn't been actively maintained, there is another fork of it here that has had some work on it: https://github.com/lmachens/meteor-apm-server